# PHP Fatal error in laravel DatabaseSeeder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

Hi Guys im newly learning laravel so when i setup code to seed my tables in database, i get this error

```
Seeding: BearAppSeeder
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Bear::create() in C:\Users\mrosh\Desktop\WD\garden\database\seeds\Database
Seeder.php on line 41


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to undefined method Bear::create()
```

Here is my code in DatabaseSeeder.php file, the idea is to create table for 'bears', 'fish', 'trees' and 'picnics' and links bears to picnics "many-to-many" and seed them with some data

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Eloquent::unguard();

        // call our class and run our seeds
        $this->call('BearAppSeeder');
        $this->command->info('Bear app seeds finished.'); // show information in the command line after everything is run
    }

}

// our own seeder class
// usually this would be its own file
class BearAppSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run() {

        // clear our database ------------------------------------------
        DB::table('bears')->delete();
        DB::table('fish')->delete();
        DB::table('picnics')->delete();
        DB::table('trees')->delete();
        DB::table('bears_picnics')->delete();

        // seed our bears table -----------------------
        // we'll create three different bears

        // bear 1 is named Lawly. She is extremely dangerous. Especially when hungry.
        $bearLawly = Bear::create(array(
            'name'         => 'Lawly',
            'type'         => 'Grizzly',
            'danger_level' => 8
        ));

        // bear 2 is named Cerms. He has a loud growl but is pretty much harmless.
        $bearCerms = Bear::create(array(
            'name'         => 'Cerms',
            'type'         => 'Black',
            'danger_level' => 4
        ));

        // bear 3 is named Adobot. He is a polar bear. He drinks vodka.
        $bearAdobot = Bear::create(array(
            'name'         => 'Adobot',
            'type'         => 'Polar',
            'danger_level' => 3
        ));

        $this->command->info('The bears are alive!');

        // seed our fish table ------------------------
        // our fish wont have names... because theyre going to be eaten

        // we will use the variables we used to create the bears to get their id

        Fish::create(array(
            'weight'  => 5,
            'bear_id' => $bearLawly->id
        ));
        Fish::create(array(
            'weight'  => 12,
            'bear_id' => $bearCerms->id
        ));
        Fish::create(array(
            'weight'  => 4,
            'bear_id' => $bearAdobot->id
        ));

        $this->command->info('They are eating fish!');

        // seed our trees table ---------------------
        Tree::create(array(
            'type'    => 'Redwood',
            'age'     => 500,
            'bear_id' => $bearLawly->id
        ));
        Tree::create(array(
            'type'    => 'Oak',
            'age'     => 400,
            'bear_id' => $bearLawly->id
        ));

        $this->command->info('Climb bears! Be free!');

        // seed our picnics table ---------------------

        // we will create one picnic and apply all bears to this one picnic
        $picnicYellowstone = Picnic::create(array(
            'name'        => 'Yellowstone',
            'taste_level' => 6
        ));
        $picnicGrandCanyon = Picnic::create(array(
            'name'        => 'Grand Canyon',
            'taste_level' => 5
        ));

        // link our bears to picnics ---------------------
        // for our purposes we'll just add all bears to both picnics for our many to many relationship
        $bearLawly->picnics()->attach($picnicYellowstone->id);
        $bearLawly->picnics()->attach($picnicGrandCanyon->id);

        $bearCerms->picnics()->attach($picnicYellowstone->id);
        $bearCerms->picnics()->attach($picnicGrandCanyon->id);

        $bearAdobot->picnics()->attach($picnicYellowstone->id);
        $bearAdobot->picnics()->attach($picnicGrandCanyon->id);

        $this->command->info('They are terrorizing picnics!');

    }

}
```

so how i can fix this i have tried many things but all fails

Comment: " i have tried many things"  Such as....

Comment: a) move `BearSeeder` to its own file, b) you need to import the Bear class `use App\Bear;` at the top of the file, c) make sure Bear is extending Eloquent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `Bear` model extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` like this:

```
class Bear extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
```

otherwise `Bear` model won't have `create` method and you will get error that this method doesn't exist